# How to pass memory address of a location in Stack from assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am trying to store a stack memory address into a register. The point is to call a `c` function from assembly code that takes in three arguments.

1) A pointer to a function: which I get using `leaq label(%rip), %rdi`

2) An int: which is simple, `movq $2, %rsi`

3) A pointer to a memory address: This is the tricky part. This address is lets say stack location 2 = `-16(%rsp)`.

How to pass this stack location to the register `%rdx` and have the `c` function write its results there?

Note: This `c` function is `pthread` threaded if you need to know.

Comment: lea -16(%rsp), %rdx

Comment: Assembly for which CPU?

Comment: @EJP x86 architecture

Comment: So why wasn't that critical information stated in the question?

Comment: Look at compiler output for `foo() { int k; bar(&k); }`  https://godbolt.org/g/kfPqic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I did it, thanks. Here is the full solution:

assembly code:

```
  1 .globl main
  2 main:
  3
  4 pushq %rbp
  5 movq  %rsp, %rbp
  6 subq  $8, %rsp
  7
  8 movq  $50, -8(%rbp)
  9
 10 leaq  PrintHello(%rip), %rdi
 11 movq  $17,  %rsi
 12 leaq  -8(%rbp), %rdx
 13
 14 callq dispatcher
 15 callq wait
 16
 17 movq  -8(%rbp), %rax
 18 movq  %rax, %rdi
 19 callq print_int
 20
 21 addq  $8, %rsp
 22 movq  $0, %rax
 23 popq  %rbp
 24 retq
```

output:

```
In dispatcher arg = 17
In wait
wrap_func: args_data.ret = 50
Hello World! It's me, thread # 17!
wrap_func: after assignment-> args_data.ret = 20
Exit from wait
```